# Objective C Json not working in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *navTitle = self.navigationItem.title;

NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.twostepmedia.co.uk/json.php?q=%@",navTitle]];
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];   
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:address];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Anyone have any idea why this wouldnt work, this is in the viewDidLoad method.

Thanks

Comment: When i had a similar method to this running when i pressed a button, i would send this url upto a php page and receive a json response into a label, but now i am trying to put the method in the viewDidLoad body, it almost seems like it prints the label before its had chance to get a json response from the PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume because `self.navigationItem` is not initialized until `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: ah, ok where do i need to initialise it then? how do i structure this bit of code? thanks

Comment: Don't think this is the problem since I've accessed `self.navigationItem.title` lots of times in `viewDidLoad` (iirc)

Comment: i've just tested it by setting a label's text as the nav title and using that in the url, but instead the PHP returns "Label"...ie, it didnt receive any text from the label, just that it was a label!?

Comment: Try logging the text using `NSLog(@"Title: %@",self.navigationItem.title)` so you can see what the value actually is.